# Low-level protocol questions - here?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

I have a question on a low-level protocol (CAN), related to arbitration of the bus etc. It would be a perfect question for [Embedded Design](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50195/embedded-systems), alas...

Which SE site would currently handle this kind of questions? Specifically, not really related to *programming* (because, honestly, the programming is usually limited to setting the right parameters of the driver chip), and not really *electronics* (because it's a straightforward bus right out of Application Notes, nothing fancy on electronics level) - but related to specific use case of this protocol and its intricacies. Does SE have a site to handle that subject, or should I wait until the [Embedded Reboot](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70800/embedded-systems-programming-and-design) takes off?

Comment: You can post it at SO, as long as you tag it properly.  Use the [can] tag, don't use a widely applicable tag like [c].  Perhaps [embedded] can work.  Of course, traffic is low so don't expect a quick answer.

Comment: You can't lose rep here on Meta. Try, and, if you are told it's off-topic, you'll know.